# call to undefined function mb_strimwidth

Tags: php, string, laravel, truncation, mbstring

Months ago I made a short code that uses `mb_strimwidth()` to exactly fit some text into a table cell, putting dots at the end of a truncated string.
Now, after some times, I tried to execute that same code and it went out with this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_strimwidth() in ...
```

I tried to find the mbstring.php file, and when I found the `mb_strimwidth()` function, I discovered that it is not implemented anymore. How is that possible?
But my main question is: how can I get the same result as `mb_strimwidth()`?
I thought to rewrite the function using a loop and `mb_strwidth()`, but ALL the functions in that mbstring.php file are empty.

Comment: you mean the green tick?

Comment: ah ok. I'm sorry, I did not know that. I'm going to do it right now

Answer (score 74, accepted):

All `mb_*` functions are provided by a PHP extension called Multibyte String, internal name [mbstring](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php)

You probably don't have the extension active or installed. On most Linux distros you can install the package `php-mbstring` to install and activate this extension.

Apache needs to be restarted afterwards if you are using mod_php

Comment: ok, this solved my problem. But I don't understand what happened since last time, when it worked correctly...

Comment: You probably updated php, that's distro specific. e.g. installed php-54 packages and removed php packages.

Comment: I installed the php-mbstring in my machine and restarted the apache as well. I checked my phpinfo() after that but couldn't find php-mbstring there. I am still getting the same issue. Any help?

Comment: thank you - all the way from 2022

Answer (score 33):

Just got this issue, if you are using linux just install the package `php-mbstring`and restart Apache.

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If you are using specific PHP version, you may need to run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.x-mbstring
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Replace `7.x` by the exact PHP version.

Answer (score 5):

u need to install `php-mbstring` package try.

check php version

```
php -v
```

then check mbstring already install and enable

```
php -i | grep mbstring
```

if not installed run this command

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

> if you are **php other version**  example : **7.1, 7.2, 7.0** based on
>   run command  like this :

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mbstring
```

if you are using nginx server for run laravel .. then check nginx configration file which version u have loaded in conf file..

go to `cd /etc/nginx/sites-available` and open your configuration file..
 if you are loading php7.2 version in nginx conf file..

**fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;**

then u need to install **7.2** mbstring package..

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring
```

and **restart** apache2 server

```
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 3):

This error is mostly caused by a missing package called multibyte string or in short `mbstring`.

First check which php.ini is currently set;

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

Then check if mbstring is installed;

```
php -i | grep php-mbstring
```

If it returns nothing, then install it;

```
sudo apt install php-mbstring
```

Or you can install according to the php version installed in your workstation

```
sudo apt install php8.2-mbstring
```

Now verify that mbstring is installed;

```
php -i | grep php-mbstring
```

It should return some info.

Answer (score 1):

if you already installed mbstring then you have to call this extension on php.ini file.

First, detect where is your php-fpm.ini file or php.ini.

run command

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

it returns you path of php.ini file.

for example

```
/etc/php.ini
```

then open file with VIM or another editor

```
vim /etc/php.ini
```

and then add mbstring extension to php.ini file

```
extension=mbstring.so;
```

finally, restart php-fpm

```
systemctl restart php-fpm
```